# make with -R looks for fileName..asm not fileName.asm

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Make looking for file(dot dot).asm

I used the -R switch to avoid being overwhelmed with -d lines.  I have file findKey.s.  No problem using cpp extension with equivalent makefile statements.

What I assume to be the pertinent makefile lines:

```
CC = "f:\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin\iccarm"
ASM = "f:\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.5\arm\bin\iasmarm"

all : findKey.o intVec.o invBea.o

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) "$<" -lC "$(listDir)" -o "$(objDir)" $(dlib) $(C_allOptions) --eec++

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) "$<" -lC "$(listDir)" -o "$(objDir)" $(dlib) $(C_allOptions)

%o: %.asm
    $(ASM) "$<" -O"$(objDir)" -L"$(listDir)" -r -cM t8 --cpu Cortex-M4 --fpu None

%o: %.s
    $(ASM) "$<" -O"$(objDir)" -L"$(listDir)" -r -cM t8 --cpu Cortex-M4 --fpu None
```

[BEGIN Debug output]

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
This program is built by Equation Solution <http://www.Equation.com>
for Windows.
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[snip]
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Considering target file `findKey.o'.
   File `findKey.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `findKey.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey.'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey..asm'.  <== WHY THIS??
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey.'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey..s'.  <== AND THIS??
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey.cpp'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `findKey.cpp'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `findKey.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey.'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey..asm'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `findKey..asm'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `findKey.'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `findKey..s'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `findKey..s'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for `findKey.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `findKey.o'.
  Must remake target `findKey.o'.
```

[END Debug output]

And then it complained “no rule to make target findKey.o” and stopped.

Possible clue: I removed -R from the command line and make tried to assemble findKey.s with as which is some kind of gnu thing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at your two assembler rules:

```
%o: %.asm
    $(ASM) "$<" -O"$(objDir)" -L"$(listDir)" -r -cM t8 --cpu Cortex-M4 --fpu None

%o: %.s
    $(ASM) "$<" -O"$(objDir)" -L"$(listDir)" -r -cM t8 --cpu Cortex-M4 --fpu None
```

Those should be `%.o`, not `%o`. That would be the source of the stray double dots in your debug output and the lack of a proper "compile `.s` to `.o`" rule.